# Нужно заменить методом replace a\\\a на?

Tags: javascript, строки, replace

у меня есть функция

```
function replaceLetters(str) {
    return str.replace('a\\\\\\a', "!")
}
replaceLetters('a\a a\\a a\\\a')
```

На выходе у меня должна получиться строка `a\a a\\a !` но я получаю `aa a\a a\a`
что делаю не так? подскажите пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В строке, которую вы задаете изначально происходят преобразования и она попадает в функцию не той, какую вы видите. В этой строке надо экранировать символ `\` тоже.

```js
function replaceLetters(str) {
    return str.replace(/a\\\\\\a/g, "!")
}
console.log(replaceLetters(`a\a a\\a a\\\a`));
console.log(`a\a a\\a a\\\a`);

console.log(replaceLetters(`a\\a a\\\\a a\\\\\\a`));
console.log(`a\\a a\\\\a a\\\\\\a`);
```

Однако, есть возможность оставить строку без изменений используя в качестве тега шаблона (строки в ``) String.raw:

```js
function replaceLetters(str) {
    return str.replace('a\\\\\\a', "!")
}
console.log(replaceLetters(String.raw`a\a a\\a a\\\a`)); // Передаем в функцию строку в неизменном виде!
```